# how to combine two List with the field name in java?

Tags: java

i have two lists namely **plist** and **brlist**. **plist** has the contents of product table and the **brlist** has the pricelist of the brand table.i want to combine bothe list and make a new list.i tried the following code, but it copies the last row value of both lists.

for example,

list **plist** has **product1,product2,product3** with respective **brandnames** and brlist has **product1,product2,product3** with respective prices **price1,price2,price3**.in my case the resultant list has 3 rows with all the values are same **product3 -- brandname3 -- price3** . help me to overcome this error.

**CODE :**

```
 Map<String, Object> fields = FastMap.newInstance();
 List<Map<String, Object>> products = FastList.newInstance();

   /* actually plist and brlist has the values and displays all the values i checked */

  iter = plist.iterator();
 while (iter.hasNext())

{
  group = iter.next()

  brlist1.add(brlist.price);


  fields.put("productId",group.productId);
  fields.put("brandName",group.brandName);
  fields.put("price",brlist.price);

 products.add(fields);
}
```

Comment: This is because you are adding same `fields` object to the products list!

Comment: `java-ee` tag should be removed. This is a core Java related question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest solution for you would be to create a new object that stores both the fields that you are pulling from plist and brlist. This is sort of confusing, but if you did that then you are able to make a list of new objects that fulfill your need directly rather than creating a list of part one list and part the other. I am having a hard time following your code although your explanation is clear before, the code variables don't make a ton of sense to me.

Also, I am going to have to research it, but the calling of your methods for field seem backwards to me for some reason, albeit it has been a while since I have worked with maps/Java.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
new class Product {

private Long productId;
private String brandName;
private Double price;

constructor ...
getters / setters ...

}
```

And then somewhere in your code...

```
Map<Long, Product> products = new HashMap<Long, Product>();

// Not really certain what type of map you got here... but regardless
iter = plist.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {

  // Again, some sort of either object or identifier
  group = iter.next()

  Product p = new Product();
  p.setBrandName(group.getBrandName());
  p.setProductId(group.getProductId());

  products.put(group.productId(), p);

}

iter = brlist.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {

  group = iter.next();

  // Let's assume the both brlist and plist have the same amount of products
  // That way we can grab the value from the map and set the price.
  products.get(group.getProductId()).setPrice(group.getPrice());

}
```